# Maven 3.0.3 release:prepare on Mac OS X 10.5.8 fails

Tags: svn, macos, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to do a mvn release:prepare on a Mac OS X 10.5 which fails with the following message.

```
[INFO] Working directory: /Users/km/.../maven-release-project
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.043s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat May 21 19:23:29 CEST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/528M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.1:prepare (default-cli) on project 900-release: Unable to check for local modifications
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] /bin/sh: svn: command not found
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

The problem is svn is installed and works without any problem. (/opt/subversion/bin/svn).

Comment: Guess svn is not in your PATH.

Comment: svn is in the path...which svn prints out /opt/subversion/bin/svn and i can call it from command line without any problem.

Comment: I was actually having the same error but with mercurial instead of subversion; the problem was I had failed to initialize the mercurial directory [$ hg init]. Are you sure that you did for svn?

Comment: Just a guess: where did you set the additional PATH entry to link to /opt/subversion/bin? I am on 10.7, so no chance to check this. Did you edit /etc/profile for adding? Or .bashrc?

Comment: I've checked it and it's beeing set in the /etc/profile ..

Answer (score 0):

I created a symlink to svn binary and it helped:

```
ln -s /opt/subversion/bin/svn /bin/svn
```